# having trouble resolving a list index out range

Tags: python-2.7

I am new to python and am reading field values from a postgres database and looping through the cursor  pass the rows  to class to initialize the attribute of the class (sg_item_list) then add it to a list.

The kind of data I am reading is:

1. in one record I have this:['1','2','201562-01', 'one Handed stool'], ['3','2','201562-02', 'two Handed stool']
2. in a second record i have this too: ['4','2','78162-01', 'iphone']

Below is the code:

```
new_dsL = []
    for sg_item in dsL:
        sg_itemL = eval(sg_item.sg_item_list)
        for i_row in sg_itemL:
            if i_row[2] in boD:
                sg_item.sg_bo_ind = 'True'
        new_dsL.append(sg_item)
    dsL = new_dsL
```

In the list dsL is where I have all the sg_item_list values I assign to another list which I loop through by using the For loop iterator.

boD is a dictionary with various sku items like 201562-02.

running this code, I get the following error:

if i_row[2] in boD:
IndexError: string index out of range

I suspect that I may have a list of lists.

How do I correct this error?

Comment: Notice that you are getting a **string index** error. Then look at how long the strings in your lists are.

Comment: @Donkey Kong I used sg_itemL = eval(sg_item.sg_item_list.replace('\r','\\r').replace('\n','\\n')) to fix the string index out of range, now I am getting a different error  File "<string>", line 1
    ['2','1','201005-02',"Sleep Improving Wedge Pillow - 10""]
                                                             ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to accomplish. What's your desired output?

Comment: @DonkeyKong i saw where the error was coming from. I had some bad data that I had to care of. There were additional strings "" at the end of one of the elements of a list.